# How to create log in based on user role

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ef-core-2.0

I created a asp.net core mvc project with no authentication. How can I create role and assign it to user so that I can use role in controller to filter the acces?

Comment: Please add some code that you have tried so that the community can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASP.NET Identity for this case (setup database manually if project without authentication)

Reference at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Script for ASP.NET Identity DB at
https://github.com/pacal/Identity_SQL